# Setting Global Variables within an ASP.NET Web Project on Login and set Expiry Time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, global-variables

I'm developing a revised version of a system I have been using for years, but with all the advantages of .NET features that were not around when I first made this.

It's proving a steep learning curve!

So, when a user logs in through my Login.aspx page which simply compares username/password to Database record, the system creates a session variable containing the user's Username and various other things.

There are two type of variable which will be common to all elements of this system

1. User Specific data, Username, Permissions, etc
2. Setting variables, drawn from a database of pre-set facilities which are setup within the system, some will determine which facilities work, how they work, and some will be dependant upon the User's permission.

Obviously, I could set everything within the Session data, but that'd be inefficient wouldn't it?

If I were to set these globally available variables in my App_Code, how would I go about setting this up so that, for example, those variables which require a database call, are set for the duration of the Logged-In session and do not require constant Database lookups?

Further to that, those variables which are dependant on the session state, would need clearing on each LogOut.

I am using VB.NET.

Comment: I don't understand the point "I could set everything within the Session data, but that'd be inefficient wouldn't it?". Why wouldn't it be efficient? What is not clear, are these informations shared across all sessions? Then i would use the [ASP.NET Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using global variables is not a good idea most of the time. In webapps, global variables are even worse because the intrinsic mulituser nature of web applications.
You have to maintain a set of vars for every single user - and thats excactly what session state is built for!

So why bothering using session state? After all its (by default) just some in memory collection of data magically bound to a single users session by the ASP.NET framework for you.

> Further to that, those variables which are dependant on the session state, would need 
>   clearing on each LogOut.

Even that can be done with `Session.Abandon()` in a single line when using session state.

When caching data that is not user dependant, it would be better to use the [ASP.NET Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx) as Tim suggested.

Comment: If these variables are the same for all Users, it would be better to use the [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx). You could even restrict the access to the variables(if it depends on the user's permission) from a wrapper class that holds them.

Comment: Ok, so you're recommending storing all user dependant data as a session variable and all others using the ASP Cache? I didn't think using the Session that much would be wise, but I'm totally ready to be corrected! At least I understand how to do that!

Comment: These are datastores provided by the framework. Normally its not necessary to rebuild something similar for yourself. You havn't told us yet what your concerns about using ASP.NET session are.